# Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.Int32' exception in ADO.NET

Tags: c#, ado.net, northwind

I was trying to practice some simple ADO.NET app that would just get some data from Northwind DB and display it but it throws "Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.Int32'." exception.I had googled it and I saw that I need to handle null values but It did not work (still getting same error)

```
const string connectionString =
    "Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=True";


var employees=GetEmployees();

foreach (Employee employee in employees)
{
    Console.WriteLine( $"Name: {employee.FirstName} Last Name: {employee.LastName}");

}



static List<Employee> GetEmployees()
{

    const string queryString =
        "SELECT * FROM Employees; ";
    var employees = new List<Employee>();

    using (SqlConnection connection =
        new(connectionString))
    {

        SqlCommand command = new(queryString, connection);

        try
        {

            connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {

                Employee employee = new();
                employee.EmployeeID = (int)reader["EmployeeID"];
                employee.LastName = (string)reader["LastName"];
                employee.FirstName = (string)reader["FirstName"];
                employee.Title = (string)reader["Title"];
                employee.TitleOfCourtesy = (string)reader["TitleOfCourtesy"];
                employee.BirthDate = (DateTime)reader["BirthDate"];
                employee.HireDate = (DateTime)reader["HireDate"];
                employee.Address = (string)reader["Address"];
                employee.City = (string)reader["City"];
                employee.Region = Convert.IsDBNull((string)reader["Region"]) ? String.Empty : (string)reader["Region"];
                employee.PostalCode = (string)reader["PostalCode"];
                employee.Country = (string)reader["Country"];
                employee.HomePhone = (string)reader["HomePhone"];
                employee.Extension = (string)reader["Extension"];
                employee.Notes = (string)reader["Notes"];
                employee.ReportsTo = Convert.IsDBNull((int)reader["ReportsTo"]) ? 0 : (int)reader["ReportsTo"];
                employee.PhotoPath = (string)reader["PhotoPath"];

                employees.Add(employee);

            }
            reader.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        return employees;
    }
```

Employee.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Ado.NET
{
    public class Employee
    {
        public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
       public string TitleOfCourtesy { get; set; }
      public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime HireDate { get; set; }
        public string Address {  get; set; }
      public string City {  get; set; }
      public string? Region {  get; set; }
      public string PostalCode { get; set; }
      public string Country {  get; set; }
        public string HomePhone {  get; set; }
      public string Extension {  get; set; }
      //[Photo]
      public string Notes {  get; set; }
      public int? ReportsTo {  get; set; }
      public string PhotoPath {  get; set; }


    }
}
```

Only ReportsTo and Region have null in DB

Console Output
Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.Int32'.
Name: Nancy Last Name: Davolio

Googling the problem first and it still did not solve it

Comment: `(int)reader["ReportsTo"]` - this.

Comment: Use `reader["ReportsTo"] as int` or whichevere column it is that's causing it.

Comment: You are first casting to `int`, and then checking for DbNull. That is the wrong order

Comment: IIRC that reader should have an IsDbNull method, use that to check for null before you try to cast

Comment: I see this: `Convert.IsDBNull((int)reader["ReportsTo"])`, which tries to address the issue, but the `Convert()` call happens too late. With that code, the `[int]` cast will be attempted **first**, which is _not possible_ in the case where you have a DBNull. If you just want `0`s here, I would handle this conversion **in the SQL**, and make sure it never returns NULL in the first place.